# Add multiple storyboards in project - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

How do you create multiple storyboards in the same project using Swift? I know I have to go to File -> New -> File and then choose Storyboard, but how do I integrate that storyboard into my project and navigate to the new storyboard's views in Swift code?

Comment: I've wondered about this before myself. Actually I've wondered why someone would want or need more than one storyboard. What is your purpose for the additional storyboard?

Comment: @Suragch if you have 20-25 views per app it's very difficult to overview them in a single storyboard. You can have a default (Main) storyboard, and one for "Tutorial" for example

Comment: I want to use it for organization. My storyboard is getting really messy with so many views, so I want to divide the views into different storyboards based on their purpose. It will help out with organizing my project a little bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the desired storyboard

```
let aStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil)
```

Then instantiate desired view controller

```
let vc = aStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerIdentifier") as! UIViewController
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more question though, I have a page view controller at the beginning so when I instantiate the View Controller do I go to the Page View Controller or do I instantiate to the normal view?

Comment: it will only instantiate the view controller, it won't be presented, it's up to you how you do it, using modal style or navigation style, etc

Comment: You can also use `aStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()` if you want to instantiate the view controller marked as initial for this storyboard in the interface builder.

Comment: @pkacprzak Ok! Thanks for the tip, will use `instantiateInitialViewController()` in order to go to the initial view controllers.